# Route [] not defined. error in laravel 6.2 using Route::currentRouteName() function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6.2

I keep getting route <> when i i try to build language switcher 
route

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'{language}'],function (){

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
```

```
    <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'tw') }}" class="nav-link">TW</a>
                        </li>
```

Comment: If you're not using a named route, I doubt that `currentRouteName()` is returning anything... Did you try adding `Route::get(...)->name('home')`?

Answer (score 2):

`Route::currentRouteName()` will return `null` if route doesn't have name, try this:

```php
Route::group(['prefix'=>'{language}'],function (){

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    })->name('example_name_here');

});
```

Assign name to route to get it's name. Hope this will work